# Why do i keep getting this error when comparing string tokens to another string?

Tags: c++, string, token, tokenize

This simple function is meant to check if the string tokens passed are operators or not, if they are return true.

```
bool isOp(std::string tokens){
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
         if (tokens[i] == "+" || tokens[i] == "-" || tokens[i] == "*" || tokens[i] == "/"){
             return true;
         }

    }

}
```

However it won't compile and i get an unexpected error that says "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]", what i don't understand is that i'm not comparing a pointer to an integer, i'm comparing a string to a string? So why do i get this error and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to compare single characters, not strings. Replace all your `"` with `'` to make them character constants instead of string literals.